# Video sound not playing in iPhone without headphones (Titanium mobile)

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am developing an app where i have to play a video from a url. The video plays fine on simulator but when i play it on iphone, i cannot hear the sound without pluggin in the headphones.

Here's the code
**Alloy View**

```
<Window>
<VideoPlayer id="VideoPlayer1" autoplay="false" height="300" width="Ti.UI.FILL" backgroundColor="black" fullscreen="true"></VideoPlayer>
</Window>
```

**controller.js**

```
$.VideoPlayer1.url = "SOME_URL";
$.VideoPlayer1.play();
```

Are there any extra setting which i have to add or delete in TiApp.XML. Am  I missing a parameter or something or a property ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this . Just needed to set the volume property.

```
$.VideoPlayer1.volume = 1.0;
```